# How can I troubleshoot connectivity issues between AWS resource types that are not included in the Reachability Analyzer tool? (e.g. Lambda functions)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda, vpc

I have a Lambda function deployed into a public subnet in a VPC and I’m trying to connect to a Lambda function outside of a VPC and I’m running into connectivity issues.

I believe the security group settings and IAM policies will permit the connection, but I'm not sure if there's an issue with connecting to an out-of-VPC Lambda from an in-VPC one.

Is there a tool in AWS Console, AWS CLI or anywhere else that I can use to troubleshoot where the connection is failing? I’ve used the Reachability Analyzer before but it only works on a handful of resource types like EC2 instances.

I've tried invoking the out-of-VPC Lambda from inside my in-VPC Lambda, but the request doesn't work and I don't see any helpful information about what happened. I tried running the Reachability Analyzer, but it doesn't allow you to test if Lambda functions are reachable.

I was expecting the request to work, but I'm not sure if I need to configure a VPC interface endpoint because I'm connecting from an in-VPC Lambda to an out-of-VPC Lambda.

I’m new to networking and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Lambda function deployed into a public subnet in a VPC and I’m trying to connect to a Lambda function outside of a VPC and I’m running into connectivity issues.

The Lambda function in the VPC never gets a public IP assigned to it. So it can't connect to anything outside of the VPC. It can't use the Internet Gateway attached to the public subnet because it doesn't have a public IP.

By "connect to a Lambda function outside of a VPC" what you are really doing is connecting to the AWS API outside of the VPC. You never "connect" to a Lambda function, because Lambda functions aren't running and just sitting around idle waiting for your request. Lambda functions don't really exist until a request comes in to the [AWS Lambda Invoke API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html), at which point AWS spins up an instance of the Lambda function and passes it the invocation payload.

To fix this connectivity issue, you either need to create an [AWS Lambda VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html) in your VPC, to handle requests to the Lambda API originating in your VPC. Or you need to move the VPC Lambda function to a private subnet, with a route to a NAT Gateway. Lambda functions in private subnets can access things outside the VPC by having their requests routed through the NAT Gateway.

---

> I was expecting the request to work, but I'm not sure if I need to configure a VPC interface endpoint because I'm connecting from an in-VPC Lambda to an out-of-VPC Lambda.

That's not how VPC Interface Endpoints work. The entire purpose of VPC Interface Endpoints is to allow a resource inside your VPC to access part of the AWS API that exists outside the VPC. A VPC Interface Endpoint will absolutely allow your Lambda function running in the VPC to access the Lambda Invoke API, in order to trigger an execution of your out-of-VPC Lambda function.

Comment: Is communication between Lambdas facilitated through the "Lambda Service"? My understanding is that the Lambda Service is responsible for spinning up Lambdas when they're needed and facilitating invocations. If that's true (and Lambda `A` doesn't directly try to invoke Lambda `B`, but rather sends the request through a middleman), how does that factor into how I should configure my subnets/routes?

Comment: Yes that's true. Lambda A doesn't directly try to invoke Lambda B, but rather sends the request through a middleman. I thought I explained that well in my answer. The only bearing that it has on your subnets/routes is that you either need a Lambda VPC Endpoint in your VPC, or a route to a NAT Gateway. I thought I also explained that well in my answer. Please read the answer I gave in detail.

Comment: I was able to invoke an out-of-VPC Lambda from an in-VPC Lambda without having either of those things present. How can that be?

Comment: So it wasn't working before, which led you to ask the question, but it is working now? What did you change?

Comment: Another developer was working on this and couldn't get the request to work. They assumed there was some connection issue, but it turns out that the request payload wasn't valid for the receiving Lambda. I wasn't familiar with the problem so I assumed it was indeed a connectivity issue.It seems like there is no additional networking configuration required to allow the in-VPC Lambda to invoke an out-of-VPC Lambda through the middleman, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes you are missing something. You either have a NAT gateway already, or a VPC endpoint for Lambda in the VPC already.